# Mean of probability distributions?

Tags: distributions, mean

Mean of a random variable $X$ is its expectation.

I am interest in the new definition, mean of probability distribution**s**

Let $p,q$ be probability density distributions. $0.5p+0.5q$ is the mean distribution.

How to generalize this definition of mean to uncountable infinite number of distributions $p$?

What is the proper textbook name for this "mean"?

Comment: [mixtures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) are pretty great. Countable or uncountable infinity of distributions can be tackled with infinite series or integrals.

Comment: @Galen So I guess for my case it is "equally weighted mixture"? Do we need additional assumptions ot make sure that such mixture exist for uncountably infinite number of $p$?

Comment: A sum of an uncountable infinity is undefined: you need a measure-theoretic formulation.  That has already been accomplished for you, because a mixture in this sense can be expressed as a [convolution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=convolution+is%3Aanswer+score%3A25+-network+-CNN) of a distribution with its mixing distribution.

Comment: @dodo See whuber's comment.

Comment: @whuber Many thanks! What I saw on the Wikipedia link is that only the distribution accompanied with an additional parameter, $\alpha$, can have infinite mixture as integration. Is that true?

Comment: As I wrote, uncountable sums are undefined in mathematics, so you need some kind of concept of integration for such sums.

Comment: @whuber I think you must be correct, though I am having a hard time understanding how convolution helps with the measure-theoretic definition needed. Is convolution here means the sum of random variable and the mixture of distribution?

Comment: Generally, you need a *family* of distributions $F(x;\theta)$ parameterized by a vector $\theta\in\Theta$ where $(\Theta,\mathrm d\mu)$ is a probability space so that you can form the mixture $$\tilde F(x)=\int_\Theta F(x;\theta)\,\mathrm d\mu(\theta).$$ Defining $f_x(\theta)=F(x;-\theta),$ that expression is the convolution $(f\star \mathrm d\mu)(0).$